# How to access Xorg before login in user service that needs some X features and started by user lingering

Tags: permissions, systemd, xorg, login, services

I have a user service in `~/.config/systemd/user` which needs some X features (it needs to make some painting and image manipulation features). The unit file is something like:

```
[Unit]
Description=A Sample Service
After=network.target display-manager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/afshar/.Xauthority"
ExecStart=/home/afshar/myService.AppImage
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

It successfully activates by:

```
systemctl --user daemon-reload
systemctl --user enable --now MyService
```

I have also enabled user lingering to keep service running on user logout and on system boot before user login by:

```
loginctl enable-linger
```

Everything works as expected when there is no dependency to X. But when some features that need X are added to the service, the service does not start before user login and terminates on user logout. It seems that the lingered user does not have access right to X because there is no user session (Or may be some other problem). How can I make the this user service that needs X be sarted before login?

Answer (score 1):

Before user `afshar` logs in, `/home/afshar/.Xauthority` will not contain a valid X session cookie for the X display. It may contain an old cookie from previous login, but that got invalidated as soon as the X server reset at logout and generated a new session cookie.

It's probably impossible to grant a non-root user access to the X server before login, without also giving enough permissions to steal other users' passwords by painting a fake login dialog on top of the real one, or other trickery.

In other words, anything that can affect the login screen in any way is going to be a security-sensitive component, and is going to need sysadmin-level configuration to be present at the login screen. You must not be able to it with regular user permissions alone, or else there will be a big security weakness: the integrity of the login dialog will then be questionable, and the system will not be able to fully protect users from each other.

Likewise, silently allowing user `afshar`'s process get a copy of the new X session cookie while user `not_afshar` is logged in on the GUI would be a violation of that user's security.

You should probably implement the part that needs the X features as a separate component, that uses D-Bus or some other mechanism to communicate with the main part of the service. You could then start one instance of that component before login in the X server initialization script, so that it can do its thing in the login screen (running as root or some dedicated application user), then as an user logs in, let it die and have the user session start another instance of that component (running as the logged-in user).

This will obviously require that the main service must be able to deal with the X feature component dying and restarting, so that the connection can be re-established whenever necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I hoped there would be a more simple solution. Anyway how can i give root access rights to the user to be able to connect to X server at login in spite of the security risks?

Comment: Find the X server process in the process listing. It will be something like `Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth <pathname>`. The `<pathname>` will identify the file that holds the master copy of the current session cookie. Arrange for the user to be able to read that file (using ACLs or whatever), then the user can re-point their `XAUTHORITY` variable to it, and re-connect to the X server. Repeat this process each time the X server resets, as the X Display Manager (typically `gdm`, `sddm` or something-else-`dm`) may change the filename each time it restarts the X server.